# Combinations with specific total

Tags: combinatorics

From the values:

```
{57.02, 71.04, 87.03, 97.05, 99.07, 101.05, 103.01, 113.08, 114.04, 115.03,
 128.06, 128.09, 129.04, 131.04, 137.06, 147.07, 156.10, 163.03, 186.08}
```

I would like to find all possible combinations of 3 values that have the sum of roughly 344.25 (+/- 0.05 would be ok). I have tried:

```
IntegerPartitions[344.2, {3}, {57.0, 71.0, 87.0, 97.1, 99.1, 101.1, 103.0, 113.1, 114.0, 115.0, 128.1, 128.1, 129.0, 131.0, 137.1, 147.1, 156.1, 163.0, 186.1}]
```

though `IntegerPartitions` only seems to accept whole numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {57.0, 71.0, 87.0, 97.1, 99.1, 101.1, 103.0, 113.1, 114.0, 
   115.0, 128.1, 128.1, 129.0, 131.0, 137.1, 147.1, 156.1, 163.0,  186.1};

subsets = DeleteDuplicates @ Select[Subsets[list, {3}], 344.2 <= Total[#] <= 344.3 &]
```

> {{57., 101.1, 186.1},
>   {87., 101.1, 156.1},
>   {101.1, 115., 
>     128.1},
>   {103., 113.1, 128.1}}

```
DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ Permutations /@ subsets]
```

> {{57., 101.1, 186.1}, {57., 186.1, 101.1}, {101.1, 57., 
>     186.1}, {101.1, 186.1, 57.}, {186.1, 57., 101.1}, {186.1, 101.1, 
>     57.},
>    {87., 101.1, 156.1}, {87., 156.1, 101.1}, {101.1, 87., 
>     156.1}, {101.1, 156.1, 87.}, {156.1, 87., 101.1}, {156.1, 101.1, 
>     87.},
>    {101.1, 115., 128.1}, {101.1, 128.1, 115.}, {115., 101.1, 
>     128.1}, {115., 128.1, 101.1}, {128.1, 101.1, 115.}, {128.1, 115., 
>     101.1},
>   {103., 113.1, 128.1}, {103., 128.1, 113.1}, {113.1, 103., 
>     128.1}, {113.1, 128.1, 103.}, {128.1, 103., 113.1}, {128.1, 113.1, 
>     103.}}

Answer (score 2):

Use exact fractions for `IntegerPartitions`:

```
L = Round[{57.02, 71.04, 87.03, 97.05, 99.07, 101.05, 103.01, 113.08, 
           114.04, 115.03, 128.06, 128.09, 129.04, 131.04, 137.06, 147.07, 
           156.10, 163.03, 186.08}, 1/100];

Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[i, ∞, L], {i, 344, 345, 1/100}]

(*    {{11503/100, 11503/100, 2851/25},
       {11503/100, 11503/100, 2851/50, 2851/50},
       {10301/100, 1941/20, 8703/100, 2851/50},
       {3226/25, 6403/50, 8703/100},
       {3226/25, 2851/25, 2021/20}, 
       {3226/25, 2021/20, 2851/50, 2851/50},
       {3226/25, 8703/100, 1776/25, 2851/50},
       {6403/50, 11503/100, 2021/20},
       {11503/100, 2021/20, 1776/25, 2851/50},
       {11503/100, 8703/100, 1776/25, 1776/25},
       {4652/25, 2021/20, 2851/50},
       {4652/25, 8703/100, 1776/25},
       {3276/25, 2851/25, 9907/100},
       {3276/25, 9907/100, 2851/50, 2851/50},
       {6403/50, 2827/25, 10301/100},
       {2827/25, 10301/100, 1776/25, 2851/50},
       {1561/10, 3276/25, 2851/50},
       {3276/25, 1776/25, 1776/25, 1776/25},
       {3226/25, 12809/100, 8703/100},
       {2827/25, 8703/100, 8703/100, 2851/50},
       {10301/100, 9907/100, 1776/25, 1776/25},
       {12809/100, 11503/100, 2021/20},
       {2021/20, 9907/100, 8703/100, 2851/50},
       {9907/100, 8703/100, 8703/100, 1776/25},
       {1561/10, 2021/20, 8703/100},
       {12809/100, 2827/25, 10301/100},
       {2021/20, 2021/20, 1776/25, 1776/25}}    *)
```